Problem execution playwrigt scripts in Jenkins
I have no problem executing the playwright scripts on my desktop. However I encounter an error when executing in Jenkins.
Any idea how to resolve this error?
+ npx playwright test
<------My ENV---->prod

Error: Playwright Test did not expect test.describe() to be called here.
Most common reasons include:
- You are calling test.describe() in a configuration file.
- You are calling test.describe() in a file that is imported by the configuration file.
- You have two different versions of @playwright/test. This usually happens
  when one of the dependencies in your package.json depends on @playwright/test.

   at cgt_crossroad_validation\tests\CrossRoad_AIR.spec.js:11

   9 | let loginClass
  10 |
> 11 | test.describe('Validation Catering invoice processing', () => {
     |      ^
  12 |
  13 |   test.beforeEach(async ({browser }, testInfo) => {
  14 |     page = await browser.newPage();

    at TestTypeImpl._currentSuite (E:\.jenkins\workspace\CrossRoad_Validation\cgt_crossroad_validation\node_modules\playwright\lib\common\testType.js:71:13)
    at TestTypeImpl._describe (E:\.jenkins\workspace\CrossRoad_Validation\cgt_crossroad_validation\node_modules\playwright\lib\common\testType.js:104:24)
    at Function.describe (E:\.jenkins\workspace\CrossRoad_Validation\cgt_crossroad_validation\node_modules\playwright\lib\transform\transform.js:256:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\.jenkins\workspace\CrossRoad_Validation\cgt_crossroad_validation\tests\CrossRoad_AIR.spec.js:11
:6)

My Jenkins file
stages {
        stage("checkout") {
                    steps {
                        checkoutRepo(branch, project, cgtx_repo)
                    }
                }

        // stage('Install Playwright') {
        //     steps {
        //         sh 'npm install -g playwright'
        //     }
        // }
        
        stage('Install dependencies') {
             steps {
              dir('cgt_crossroad_validation') {
                     // Execute npm install within the changed directory
                     sh 'npm install'
                 }
             }
         }
        stage('Run Playwright Tests') {
            steps {
                    sh 'npx playwright test'
                }
            }
        }

In the jenkins file whether I execute npm install or not I get the same result.

,I think you are not running the command in the exact directory where it supposed to be run . Please check once.

Also check the correct casing in your file paths like in case you are typing all in lowercase where some of the part is not in lowercase.

Check two things:

Are you inside the right directory ? Are you running the commands inside a folder where you are supposed to run?

Are you giving all file paths with the correct casing? May be like you typed all in lower case or changed casing at later stage.



Thank you, I added directory in the Jenkins file , it is working
dir('cgt_crossroad_validation') {
// Execute  within the changed directory
sh 'npx playwright test'
            }

